# How do I insert HTML onto every page?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

I've got the following code in my module. I'm trying to get it to insert some HTML, ideally at the start of `<body>`, but it seems that my call in `hook_init()` isn't working - what would be the right hook to call this in? I'm hoping it will just render slidedown.tpl.php after `<body>`.

```
<?php
function slidedown_init() {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'slidedown') . '/slidedown.js');
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'slidedown') . '/slidedown.css');
    slidedown_insert_html();
}

function slidedown_insert_html() {
    return theme('slidedown_template');
}

function slidedown_theme() {
    $themes = array (
        'slidedown_template' => array(
            'template' => 'slidedown', // your template file called slidedown.tpl.php
            'arguments' => array(),
        ),
    );
    return $themes;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want [`hook_page_build()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7):

```
function slidedown_page_build (&$page) {
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'slidedown');

  drupal_add_js($path . '/slidedown.js');
  drupal_add_css($path . '/slidedown.css');

  $page['page_top']['slidedown_template'] = array(
    '#weight' => -1000, 
    '#markup' => theme('slidedown_template'),
  );
}
```

I can't remember if that hook is too late to add JS and CSS.  You may need to put those in a [`template_preprocess_html()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7).  That is a better choice that [`hook_init()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7).

Answer (score 1):

The template page.tpl.php and its variants define what is placed within the <body></body> tags.

It will probably be better to define a region in page.tpl.php and place it where you want. Then render your slideshow in this region.

For more information check out [How the Drupal theme system works](http://drupal.org/node/337173).